# How to only load a certain syntax file

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Okay, so I have a syntax file `asciidoc.vim` in `~/.vim/syntax` and this file is actually loaded, as I checked with `scriptnames`.
But for some reason, it only works, if the builtin syntax files haven't loaded (and applied).

Is there some way only to make the syntax files load that I specify?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the builtin syntax file `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/asciidoc.vim`, you'll see near the top, this:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif
```

and near the bottom, this:

```
let b:current_syntax = "asciidoc"
```

So, if you put that last line in your own `asciidoc.vim`, the builtin `asciidoc.vim` will see that value and `finish` early.

See also:

```
:help mysyntaxfile-replace
```